# Will BeginInvoke continue to execute if I return immediately from an MVC controller action?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue where we believe an Async call may not execute in some instances.

- Would **doWork()** complete executing even after the controller has returned and no call to **EndInoke()**?
- Is there another case where this would not execute, like an exception throw in **doWork()**?

```cs
delegate void TestDelegate();
void doWork()
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
public ActionResult Test()
{
    var myAsyncCall = new TestDelegate(doWork);
    myAsyncCall.BeginInvoke();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I used indents but it didn't format correctly

Comment: It would seem you could easily find this out by trying it yourself, e.g. by observing a side-effect created in `doWork` such as writing to the console, creating a file or throwing an exception. You would likely find that (1) yes, it keeps executing after the controller has returned and (2) throwing will likely crash your application.

Comment: @Alex I cannot reproduce this locally but have seen this a few times in our  production environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you need to call `EndInvoke` on the delegate.  This will allow you to determine why things are not working (like an exception being raised within `doWork`, which would explain the described issue).

For details, see [Calling Synchronous Methods Asynchronously](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

That being said, I would recommend reworking this to use the the TPL instead of `delegate.BeginInvoke`, as it makes some of the checking simpler overall.  You could write the above as:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    // Start the async work, and attach a continuation which happens if exceptions occur
    Task.Run(() => doWork())
    .ContinueWith(t =>
    {
       var ex = t.Exception.InnerException;
       LogException(ex);
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Reed. I'll try this shortly and post the results.

Comment: I did a bunch of testing with and without calling EndInvoke and no matter the length I set the thread to sleep it always seemed to work fine. Still confused about the inner workings but I ended up adding more logging and going with TPL since it's much cleaner. Thanks again for the help.